# Magnetic Flux penetrating a closed loop of area A

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Consider that we have a wire containing current $I$ and there is a closed square loop of area $A$ and we need to calculate the flux penetrating this loop. First, we know that the field B due to a current carrying conductor is 
$$B= \frac{\mu I}{2\pi r},$$ 
where $r$ is the point we measure the field at. Also, we know that the flux is equal to

$$\int BdA$$

Now, in some textbooks $I$ see that the flux is equal to

$$\int_a^b \frac{\mu I}{2\pi r} \cdot L \cdot dr, $$

*$L$ = length of conductor*

*$a$ = the horizontal distance from the conductor to the first edge of the loop in the $x$-direction*

*$b$ = the horizontal distance from the conductor to the second edge of the loop.*

My problem is  with this $dr$. According to my understanding , this $dr$ has appeared because of the surface differential element $dA$, which should be equal to $dx \cdot dy$ and consequently we will end with a two integrals for the flux with one for $dx$ and the other for $dy$.

For this problem, the integration along $dy$ will end with $L$ (If we assume that the width of the loop is $L$) and $dx$ will be $dr$ and defined as I have mentioned above as the distance starting from the conductor to the edges of the loop.

This is not making sense to me , I think my understanding is wrong because when we substitute with $B , r$ will be integrated with $dr$ and therefore $dr$ is not the horizontal distance because $r$ is any distance with any direction from the conductor.

Please someone clarify this!

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how the square is placed and oriented relative to the wire. From the context, I guess that the wire is in the plane of the square, and that two sides of the square are parallel to the wire, and the other two sides are oriented radially outwards from the wire.

Suppose then, the wire is along the $y$-axis, and the square is in the $x$-$y$ plane at positive values of $x$. The field then points in $z$-direction. In the $x$-$y$ pane, where $z=0$, you have the distance to the wire
$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+z^2}=x, $$
and therefore
$$ dr = dx . $$
From this you can connect to your own reasoning about the problem.